# Question concerning the Dihedral group

Tags: abstract-algebra

According to Wikipedia, the dihedral group $D_n$ is the group of all rotations and reflections which map a $n$-polygon to itself. Further the cardinality of $D_n$ is $2n$. I see this for $n \geq 3$ but not for $n =1,2$. Since for $n=1$ we have only a point and thus the dihedral group consists of the identity map only and for $n=2$ which is a line we have the identity, a rotation and a reflection. What am I missing?

Comment: $D_1$ is isomorphic to $Z_2$ and $D_2$ is isomorphic to the Klein-four group. So all is well.

Comment: Yes I saw this but I am not sure why this is true.

Comment: For $D_1$ you've missed the reflection; for $D_2$ you've missed the composition of a rotation and reflection (which is a reflection about _the other_ axis).

Comment: Ah nice. I thought it is just the identity.